# get the index of mysql result

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM mydb ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5
```

it will display 5 lines of query, imagine that the result is like this:

```
name      |    score
__________|___________
afrig     |    500
aminuddin |    490
andi      |    420
rosyid    |    400
hasbi     |    350
```

if i have a `name` parameter, `andi` as an example, how to get number `2`(zero based) as andi's rank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(name) from mydb where score>(select score from mydb where name='andi')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you just want the query to return only 'andi' it will be like this...

```
SELECT * FROM mydb ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 2,1
```

Comment: i don't know what andi's rank is, i just have andi as a parameter, i want to get andi's rank?